# How to change highlight color for icons in outliner panel

Tags: interface, customization, theme

I'm quite colorblind and can't easily see the orange highlight behind the icon of a selected item in the outliner.  I've been all through the themes preferences but the color doesn't seem to come from the outlines sub-panel.  I would be very grateful for any guidance.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 13):

The colour in the outliner seems to be linked to the outline colour of the active object in the 3D view.

You can change this colour in *User Preferences> Themes> 3D View> Active Object:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also the color behind the selected items in a multi-item selection can be set by changing *User Preferences> Themes> 3D View> Object Selected*. 
It is usually set to a lower alpha, which makes it hard to see on lighter theme backgrounds.[image]