# How do you draw a path on a surface?

Tags: lines

What is a good way to draw a path on a surface in Blender?

[image: Paths on a surface]

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by 'path'? What is it for? What's the context? What are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: Just for illustration purposes, I want to show that you could walk along any of those "paths"/lines and end up in the same spot as where you started.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159028/scientific-illustration-non-photorealistic-rendering-of-sparse-wireframe-with-d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Edit Mode, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> an edge to select its loop, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to duplicate it without moving it, and separate it into a different object by pressing <kbd>P</kbd> > *Separate by Selection*.

[image: separate]

Do this for both loops separately, so that you end up with two loops in two different objects:

[image: objs]

Back in object mode, select one of the loop object, hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Grease Pencil* > *Object Line Art*:

[image: line art]

Set the color you want in the Line Art Object's material:

[image: material]

Repeat for the other loop object:

[image: loops]

As you can see, the red one is only partially visible. To fix this, go in its modifier settings, Occlusion panel, enable Range and play with the End value:

[image: occlusion]